# resolveLocalFileSystemURL TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined TypeError

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I am working on ionic 4 ( capacitor ). I am trying to resolve a local file system URL so I used this function `resolveLocalFilesystemUrl` but unfortunately,  I am getting this error

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

This is my code:

    `constructor(private _file: NativeFile) {}
...
..
          this._file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(nativeFilePath).then((entry: Entry) => {
   console.log(entry);
});`

Note that this function returns a promise

Comment: It _should_ return a promise, according to the documentation. Albeit, if I check it, it returns undefined, which is precisely why the error is thrown. And for me that happens on Ionic 5 with Cordova. So, that covers a wide range of possibilities, between 4 and Capacitator.

Comment: Question: does your error occur when you run it in the browser on your desktop, or after you deployed it to a mobile? For me it's in the browser, haven't deployed it to Android yet.

Comment: Just so you don't have to try it: Thought it might have to do with File needing the platform to be ready after checking on the github page for the cordova file-plugin [https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file] which, in turn, was referenced by the (rudimentary) manual of the File API on ionicframework.com mentioned below. So, I wrapped the routines that use File into the platform.ready.then() promise, which reduced the error I was getting in my unit tests to a warning, but that one still had the same message as the error and beyond that, nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you are using the right plugin. This is the one you need: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';

...

constructor(private _file: File) { }

this._file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(nativeFilePath).then((entry: Entry) => {
   console.log(entry);
});
```

**Edit**

Are you sure the method returns a promise? According to some documentation, the method accepts a callbakc function. So your code will be something like:

```
this._file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(
  nativeFilePath,
  (entry: Entry) => console.log(entry),
  err => console.log(err)
);
```

**EDIT 2**

I am working on a cordova based project (Ionic 4) an I am using the officially suggested plugin: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file . It is also supported in capacitor projects.
Form the official documentation:

> You also need a FileEntry object to read an existing file. Use the
>   file property of FileEntry to get the file reference, and then create
>   a new FileReader object. You can use methods like readAsText to start
>   the read operation. When the read operation is complete, this.result
>   stores the result of the read operation.

```
function readFile(fileEntry) {
  fileEntry.file(function (file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = function() {
      console.log("Successful file read: " + this.result);
      displayFileData(fileEntry.fullPath + ": " + this.result);
    };

    reader.readAsText(file);

  }, onErrorReadFile);
}
```

[Official Ionic Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file)
[Official plugin documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#readFile)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've updated the plugin that I am using but I am still facing the same issue :(

Comment: I am still facing the same issue :(

Comment: oh, wow, I am just joining in the party, then. Same problem here. The documentation says it should return a Promise https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/file/
When I try the approach with the callback function, I am getting flagged that "Expected 1 arguments but got 3" by Sublime.

Comment: also, @Gabriel Bianconi: could you maybe reference the "some documentation" that you are mentioning above, please?

Comment: I am getting a similar error if, instead of resolveLocalFilesystemUrl I use readAsText. Well actually, the error message is _exactly_ the same

Comment: @yogibimbi this is the link: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/ but is cordova documentation. I will update my answer with a new approach you can try

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, forgot to link that, but already had a go at it. Question: did you manage to make it work in the browser, like, at all? I see you edited your approach, so I will see if the changes make it work for me. I find it just a bit surprising that, given the scale of adaptation of the Ionic framework, such an issue seems to go unnoticed for quite some time and there is so little feedback on it, even now...

Comment: still not making much progress here, the alternative with the two callbacks in "Edit" does not work, the compiler (and editor) both throw the error that only one parameter is needed, which means it expects the path and returns a promise. And I never make it to Edit 2 since I have no way of obtaining a FileEntry object. 

I also get compilation errors when I use window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI or .resolveLocalFileSystemURL which are both suggested by my editor in code completion. I'll check out getFile next... :-$

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I found the solution!
Have you installed the ionic native file plugin?
I dont know capacitor but with cordova :
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

The plugin probably does not have permission to access the storage, resulting in all functions and properties returning undefined.

Have you added the needed permission to config.xml?

```
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
```